# Azure WebApps + Azure File share with multicontainers

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-files, azure-storage-files

I have been trying to setup my Postgresql db with my API. My API is on Azure WebApps and db on Azure fileshare.

The following is my docker compose file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: postgres
     volumes:
       - db_path:/var/lib/postgresql/data
     restart: always
     environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: dbuser
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dbuser's_password
        POSTGRES_DB: db_1

   api:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: <my registry>.azurecr.io/api:latest
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always
```

My WebApp -> Configuration -> Path mappings is below
[image]

It did get deployed but I couldn't find my database files in my Azure fileshare's location. Now as I am redeploying, I can see the following in the `Log Stream`.

[image]

Can somebody show me where did I do wrong? Why my DB is not in my Azure fileshare?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**:

Along with what Charles suggested as below:
[image]

I also have updated my docker-compose.yml file as below. The changes I made is I kept my volume name same as mapping name and added `driver_opts`:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql
     volumes:
       - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
     environment:
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbName
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=MyRootPassword!
       - MYSQL_USER=dbUser_1
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=dbUser_1'sPassword
     restart: always

   api:
     depends_on:
       - db
     entrypoint: ["./wait_for.sh", "db:3306", "-t", "3600", "--", "execute", "api"] #waiting very long enough to set the db server up and running
     image: <my registry's url>/api:latest
     ports:
       - "80:80"
     restart: always

volumes:
  mysql:
        driver: azure_file
        driver_opts:
          share_name: Azure_Share_Name
          storage_account_name: Azure_Storage_Account_Name
          storageaccountkey: Azure_Key
```

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue. When you mount using the persistent volume with Azure File Share, then the mount path will have the `root` owner and group, and you can't change it. So it the application needs the path with a special user, like this issue, the Postgresql needs the mount path `/var/lib/postgresql/data` having `postgres` owner, then it can't be achieved.

Note that the screenshot you provide with the path mapping shows the wrong mount path with the configuration in your YAML file. It may be a mistake.

Comment: Thanks Charles for the answer but it didn't work.

Comment: @Kishan What is the situation now? Did you get another error or the same error? What do you mean didn't work? My answer shows the reason why you got the error and you cannot solve it.

Comment: I am still on early stage of testing but your solution worked when I switched my database to `MSSql Server` but it didnt work for `MySQL` and `Postgres`.

Comment: @Kishan All the containers on Web App mount with File Share work like this. So if you said it doesn't work for MySQL and Postgres, what is the error you get?

Comment: @Kishan Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: I have updated the question to include my changes I did to make it work.

Comment: @Kishan Do you mean the `entrypoint` in the docker-compose?

Comment: I added `volume` and other options related to `azure` that solved my issue.